# Menu Boostrap en Celular no se queda anclado arriba

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Buenas noches amig@s solicitu de su ayuda. el caso es el siguiente

Tengo una web online y estoy teniendo una dificultad con el menu lo que sucede es que si se ve la web desde la pc si yo selecciono alguna opción del menú todo bien la web hace scroll y el menú siempre queda pegado arriba, el detalle es que si la web se ve desde un celular el menú sale pero si hago scroll y voy bajando en la pagina el menú me desaparece no me queda anclado arriba.
Yo quiero que aunque baje en la paginao haga scroll el menu siempre aparezca asi como aparece en la pc, pero en el movil no logro hacer eso.

Les dejare la web para que la vean y ojala entiendan a lo que me refiero

[Esta es la web para que la vean](http://joshuaspaintingandremodeling.com/)

Este es el codigo que tengo

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>

      </div>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#about" class="page-scroll">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services" class="page-scroll">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portafolio" class="page-scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
          <li><a href="#portafolio" class="page-scroll">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Visitando la página en móvil, el menú se queda fijo en la parte superior. El único problema que noto es la imagen del pintor, le estás definiendo un ancho fijo en pixeles y hace que desordene el ancho del body en general. Yo te recomiendo usar porcentajes, pero eso ya es otro tema

Answer (score 0):

Probaste agregando la class de Bootstrap ***sticky-top*** o ***class="position-sticky***"? agregandola en el div contenedor de todo tu menu.

Luego inspecciona tu web y prueba en el modo responsive a ver que sucede al scrollear.

Podes ver opciones en https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: No es necesario, ya está utilizando la clase `navbar-fixed-top` propia de BS